# How to store git commit hash during TFS build for display on a page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tfs, tfsbuild

How can I get the current commit hash from git and store it somewhere so that I can display it on an ASP.net MVC page?  Does TFS expose that information anywhere?  Is there some consistent way I can do it whether I build on a TFS server or locally?

Comment: The commit ID is stored with the build and is displayed on the build page. Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you need something like this, it'll most likely be a custom MsBuild task (to make it available locally) or a custom Team Build Activity.

On the build server the current Commit hash or tag (depending on how the build was queued) is available as part of the IBuildDetails.

On the client you can use LibGitSharp or invoke the git commandline to grab the current commit in your workspace and put it somewhere in the output directory.

But if you want to know if there is a standard, default way, then no.